# Blank Solution in Visual Studio gets overwritten when I create a child project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Ok,
I must have done this a thousand times, but today it has stopped working.

I create a new blank solution. Then I right click on that **Add** > **New Project** I select C# class library. Every time I have done this in the past it has created a nested child project. However, now it seems to decide to change it so that I am now in the project I just created so I have no way of creating any siblings.

I have not made any configurations changes that I can recall, and projects that I have previously created work as expected and I can create child projects in those.

This is really stumped me so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Click **Tools** then **Options**. Select **Project and Solutions** group, the option **Always show solution** should be checked.

Comment: When you right click on the solution > new project, in the browse bar at the botton is it showing correctly the location of your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this checkbox: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Always show solution

Comment: Thanks so much. That was driving me crazy

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio Tools/Options / Projects and Solutions - make sure 'Always show solution' is checked.